# Ionic app crash when use firebase and google play service api

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, gradle

I'am using firebase and google analytics plugins in my app.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0
```

with this configurations app is  crashing / stopped when build success.
I tried another  solution

when use with classpath `com.google.gms:google-services:+`
And added some changes in `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects 
{ 

  maven{ 
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
  }

}
```

then showing error : `Could not find method getCompileConfiguration() for arguments [] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl`

Comment: Did you add google() inside your repository??@anuj namjoshi

Comment: Yes i did then it showing Error: Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'debugCompile' to configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :CordovaLib.

Comment: add this in the build.gradle file `compile project(':CordovaLib')` @anuj namjoshi

Answer (score 1):

Android plugin `3.0.0` requires Gradle version `4.1` or higher.

If you're opening an existing project using Android Studio `3.0` or later, follow the prompts to automatically update an existing project to the compatible version of Gradle.

To update Gradle manually, edit the URL in gradle-wrapper.properties to the following:

```
distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```